# Quick select algorithm working on read only input to run on CUDA

Tags: algorithm, sorting, cuda, gpu

I am looking for an algorithm similar to quick select that does not change its input. I prefer to have data as read only so it will be more memory efficient to execute on CUDA GPU.

Comment: What is wrong with quick select in your example?

Comment: Wikipedia example of quick select does partial sort of input array.All the ones I could find on the internet do this. For example here http://blog.teamleadnet.com/2012/07/quick-select-algorithm-find-kth-element.html

Comment: Right, forgot about that. In that case I don't think you have other choise as to keep track of top k elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you want to avoid the allocation of temporary memory on the GPU, which most *sensible* sort and/or select algorithms would do, based on your statement "so it will be more memory efficient to execute on CUDA GPU".

Let me start by saying that I think this may be a bad idea, because although you might have satisfied your idea of "memory efficiency", you will almost certainly cripple the performance of any algorithm in so doing.  Giving either a sort or select algorithm temporary space to keep track of the work it has done is likely to yield a much faster code, at the expense of the aforementioned temporary memory allocation.

With that preface, here is one possible approach: a brute-force algorithm that orders the elements in a read-only array until it has found the one that satisfies the given selected item.   The basic idea is quite simple: for each item in the read-only input array, count the number of items in the *entire* array that are above it (for a descending-sort order).  Duplicates require special case handling, but I've included that.  Once the selected item has been found, the search can be called off.

Here's a fully worked example, with result validation:

```
$ cat t729.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// for validation
#include <algorithm>

#define DSIZE 10000
#define RG    1000
#define SELECT_ITEM 100

#define nBLK  64
#define nTPB  256

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)



#define DESCEND true
#define ASCEND  false



template <bool descending, typename T>
__global__ void my_select(const T *data, const unsigned length, const unsigned select, volatile int *index){

  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  while ((*index == -1) && (idx < length)){
    T my_val = data[idx];
    unsigned my_index = 0;
    // count the number of values higher (or lower) than me
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < length; i++){
        T temp = data[i];
        if (descending){ // request to select item in descending order
          if (temp > my_val) my_index++;
          else if ((temp == my_val) && (i < idx)) my_index++; // handle duplicates
          }
        else {  // request to select item in ascending order
          if (temp < my_val) my_index++;
          else if ((temp == my_val) && (i < idx)) my_index++; // handle duplicates
          }}
    if (my_index == select) *index = idx;
    idx += blockDim.x*gridDim.x;
    }
}

int main(){

  int *h_data, *d_data, *d_result, h_result = -1;
  h_data = (int *)malloc(DSIZE*sizeof(int));
  if (h_data == NULL) {printf("malloc fail\n"); return -1;}
  cudaMalloc(&d_data, DSIZE*sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc(&d_result, DSIZE*sizeof(int));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail");
  for (int i =0; i < DSIZE; i++) h_data[i] = rand()%RG;
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, DSIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_result, &h_result, sizeof(int),   cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy fail");
  my_select<DESCEND><<<nBLK, nTPB>>>(d_data, DSIZE, SELECT_ITEM, d_result);
  cudaMemcpy(&h_result, d_result, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy/kernel fail");
  printf("the item index at select position %d is %d, item value = %d\n", SELECT_ITEM, h_result, h_data[h_result]);
  // validation
  std::sort(h_data, h_data+DSIZE);
  printf("the item value at that sorted position is                %d\n", h_data[(DSIZE-1) - SELECT_ITEM]); // assumes DESCEND

  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t729 t729.cu
$ ./t729
the item index at select position 100 is 2858, item value = 990
the item value at that sorted position is                990
$
```

In my opinion, a better approach is to make a copy of your input data, and pass that copy to a GPU-optimized selection algorithm of your choosing, such as [this one](https://code.google.com/p/ggks/)  and let that algorithm use whatever temporary space it needs.  That will certainly be faster than the above approach, and probably faster than anything you're likely to come up with that uses no temporary space.

Comment: I'm hard-pressed to think of a scenario where O(N) space (or less, if Riko's idea of a min-heap would suit) and O(N) runtime is not preferable to the work-inefficient solution posted here.